# vaadin heroku git deployment with procfile

Tags: heroku

I tried to set up a vaadin app to heroku with the help of the heroku documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner
Everything is fine until "Deploy your application to Heroku"

I added `web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war` as my procfile to my repo

```
2021-03-30T20:25:39.612799+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ClassLoaderAwareServletContainerInitializer.lambda$onStartup$2(ClassLoaderAwareServletContainerInitializer.java:81)
2021-03-30T20:25:39.612892+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ClassLoaderAwareServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(ClassLoaderAwareServletContainerInitializer.java:123)
2021-03-30T20:25:39.613017+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
2021-03-30T20:25:39.613101+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
2021-03-30T20:25:39.613211+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 22 more
2021-03-30T20:25:39.967913+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blooming-bastion-05180.herokuapp.com request_id=f9bba12a-2b7f-4429-83df-ce0efe8e87a4 fwd="212.18.221.90" dyno=web.1 connect=5000ms service=19193ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-03-30T20:25:40.040567+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-30T20:25:40.123930+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

```
My pom file is auto generated from vaadin:
...
 <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <vaadin.version>19.0.0</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
       
        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons: https://vaadin.com/directory -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>        
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Fusion is only supported in Spring Boot currently, exclude obsolete dependencies -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fusion-endpoint</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added to provide logging output as Flow uses -->
        <!-- the unbound SLF4J no-operation (NOP) logger implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>jetty:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <!-- We use jetty plugin, replace it with your favourite developing servlet container -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.36.v20210114</version>
            </plugin>

            <!--
                Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
                package.json and main.js files.
                It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.heroku</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>9.0.41.0</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

The app is running fine locally. Does anybody know why heroku is crashing on startup?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this framework but have you tried these instructions? https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/cloud-deployment/heroku

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I also found this documentation, however, they are deploying a jar file to heroku and I am actually deploying a war file. That's why I didn't go on with it.
In the meantime I also tried to change to the jetty runner as described in https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/1571029/vaadin-on-heroku - It's still the same error.